# Как создать многомодульный maven web проект?

Tags: maven, java

Доброго времени суток. Как создать многомодульный maven проект я знаю,как создать просто web-проект через maven, я тоже знаю, но как сделать то, что обрисовано след схемой:

```
ear
- pom.xml

ejb
- pom.xml

web
- pom.xml

pom.xml
```

В web предполагается разместить index.jsp и сервлеты. Буду благодарен за ссылку на туториал)

Comment: ровно так как вы и написали:  
1) pom project - (root) настройки (modules: jar, war, ear)  
2) jar project - (ejb) backend  
3) war project - frontend (dependencies: jar)  
4) ear project - packager (dependencies: jar, web)  

`jar, war, ear` - packaging для проэктов

если надо могу накидать помики

Comment: да, очень надо! а то есть пример, а там или плагины кривые или еще что... буду очень благодарен, целый день вожусь...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

файловая структура:

```
test-proj
    - ear
    - ejb
    - war
```

root pom.xml :

```
<groupId>com.test.group</groupId>
<artifactId>test-proj</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>ejb</module>
    <module>war</module>
    <module>ear</module>
</modules>
```

ejb pom.xml:

```
<artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.test.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-proj</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

war pom.xml:

```
<artifactId>war</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.test.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-proj</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>jar</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

ear pom.xml:

```
<artifactId>ear</artifactId>
<packaging>ear</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.test.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-proj</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>jar</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.test.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>war</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

p.s. упущены только теги `project` и `modelVersion` (во всех помах)

Comment: спасибо! правда я там заменил, где надо, jar на ejb и war на web в dependecies, но не суть.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kxag12qilklvsg1/ear-1.0.ear
вот мой ear-ник. Вы не подскажете, по какому адресу мне достучаться до вложенной в war-ник index.jsp? а то что-то в голову не приходит = (

Comment: доступ идет по настройках web проэкта (т.е. war): http://<server>:<port>/war/[index.jsp]

последнее опционально т.к. index должен автоматически подтягиватся. если есть сомнения можете открыть ear (обычный zip архив), `META-INF/application.xml`:

    <application>
      <display-name>ear</display-name>
      <module>
        <web>
          <web-uri>web-1.0.war</web-uri>
          <context-root>/web</context-root>
        </web>
      </module>
    </application>

`context-root` - то что вас интересует

Comment: http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-web-server/how-to-deploy-a-web-application-on-the-root-context-on-jboss-as-7

я вот тут подобное прочитал, но затупил, ввел неправильный web-uri (версию к имени файла не добавил), да еще и перед context-root вставлял uri от ear-ника... = (
спасибо большое, что подробно так написали!!!
вопрос не по теме - а есть у Вас туториал или книга (хотя думаю такой нет), где можно все эти тонкости сборок и структур проектов почитать? а то приходится пол-инета перерывать днями, чтобы найти ответ?)

Comment: боюсь книжки нету, давно уже не читал их =/ 

разобратся во всем конечно стоит, но для начала темплейта который я привел должно быть достаточно для того чтоб собрать рабочий веб прожект (не считая 3rd-party dependencies). `war`, `ear` - мейвен соберет за вас (включая конфигурационные файлы), `ejb` - контейнер автоматически подтянет по аннотациям. при деплое на сервер (tomee, jboss) сервер пишет на какой context-url задеплоилось приложение...

влезать (в дебри) или не влезать - вот в чем вопрос...

Comment: вопрос такой - что такое этот context-root? я провел эксперименты - писал туда все что угодно, а в результате заходил только по localhost:8080/web/ 
допустим, я хочу изменить стартовый url, как это сделать?

Comment: это часть url которая идет сразу после имени сервера (+порта). приложение подписывается автоматически на все запросы которые идут на этот урл (и возможно все низлежащие). у вас скорее за все не срабатывало т.к. файлик генерится автоматически